# Можно ли вместо запятой ставить тире в СПП?

Tags: запятые, тире, спп

Нашла в одной книге такие предложения:

1. Я заработал восемь месячных зарплат за два дня - потому что с каждого приведенного человека оставлял себе справедливую комиссию.
2. Начались проблемы - когда снимали офис, договорились заплатить потом.
3. Где и как заработать достаточно денег, чтобы и жилье снять и детей прокормить - у одного из которых ДЦП.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому правилу здесь ставятся тире. Я всегда такие предложения воспринимала как СПП и думала, что между частями ставится запятая. Может, есть какой-то момент, который я упускаю? Где об этом можно прочитать?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138192/discussion-on-question-by---------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ на комментарии**

**Пример 1.** *Я заработал восемь месячных зарплат за два дня, **потому что** с каждого приведенного человека оставлял себе справедливую комиссию.*

«А почему нельзя интонационное тире? А почему нельзя присоединение за счёт усиления знака?»

Вероятно, этот вопрос о замене запятой **тире как более сильным знаком.**

Как известно, тире в СПП может использоваться как **неосновной знак**, заменяя запятую.

Собственно говоря, **усиление знака** – это увеличенная пауза между предложениями там, **где это нужно,** а не в любом случае. Розенталь называет это **интонационным отделением** главной части СПП от придаточной и подробно рассматривает все эти варианты: [§ 38. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142).

Чаще всего интонационное отделение связано **со структурой предложения**, иногда – при большом количестве **запятых**, при наличии слов ***это, вот***, в случае **однородных придаточных**. Но в заданном предложении **нет никаких показаний** для такого интонационного отделения.

Также нет никаких оснований **для присоединительных отношений** в этом предложении с придаточным причины. **СПП с придаточными присоединительными** – это особый вид СПП, например: *Он нарушил обещание, **из-за чего** мы с ним поссорились. Я его пригласил, **почему** он и пришёл.* В таких СПП придаточное стоит на втором месте и отделяется запятой, а для связи используются **союзные слова**, а не союзы.

**Пример 2.**  *Начались проблемы (какие именно?) – **когда снимали офис, договорились заплатить потом.***

«Уже понял вашу мысль. Но у меня иначе: Начались проблемы в то время, как [когда] снимали офис. Нужен контекст».

**Другая разбивка:** *Начались проблемы, когда снимали офис – **договорились заплатить потом.***

Контекст  действительно нужен, но тире уже стояло в этом предложении.

**Пример 3.**

*Где и как заработать достаточно денег, чтобы и жилье снять, и детей прокормить – **у одного из которых ДЦП.***

«Скобки ни к чему. В скобках наименее важная информация, а у нас важная, её желательно подчеркнуть интонационным тире».

Информация обособлена тире **как дополнительная**, но для такого оформления нужна **подходящая структура** предложения. Мы же имеем **придаточное определительное предложение**, представленное в виде присоединительной конструкции, что выглядит **некорректно** (придаточное должно стоять после определяемого слова).

**При редактировании** надо просто поставить (по правилам) придаточное после существительного: *Где и как заработать достаточно денег, чтобы снять жилье и прокормить детей, **у одного из которых ДЦП.***

И тогда нет никакой необходимости выделять эту информацию как дополнительную и **считать особо важной.**

Если этого не сделать, то лучше заключить придаточное определительное в скобки: *Где и как заработать достаточно денег, чтобы и жилье снять, и детей прокормить **(у одного из которых ДЦП).***

**Примечание**

Я подробно разобрала эту тему, по которой мне были **заданы вопросы**. Я **не увиливаю** от сложностей, но не считаю необходимым каждый раз тратить значительное время на такие **подробные дополнительные** ответы, к тому же заданные не в виде просьбы, **а в виде достаточно жесткой критики.**

Comment: 1. Имею в виду добавление. Если там добавление, а не обычное придаточное, как это показать? Вот от этого вы постоянно увиливаете. 3. Скобки уместны, если об этой проблеме уже было известно. Выделение там не помешает, интонационное тире ставится перед неожиданной информацией, перед очень важной информацией, чтобы сделать на ней акцент.

Comment: Ещё вот что: вы же знаете про повышенные тона, для того, чтобы это передать, требуется интонационное тире. Может, автору это было нужно.

Comment: Может, быть...  А вот о чем я могу сказать с полной уверенностью –  мы с вами говорим на разных языках. Моя последняя попытка найти контакт не удалась. Извините, oleedd, мне сложно разговаривать с вами. Давайте договоримся так: вы даете альтернативные ответы, а меня больше не комментируете.  А в своих ответах критикуйте, если что не нравится,я буду иметь в виду ваше мнение. ОК?

Comment: Почему на разных? Вашу позицию уже понимаю. Что вы у меня не понимаете? Да и редко критикую ваши ответы. Чаще всего они у вас верны.

Comment: Ну, как вам сказать? Я – человек с другой планеты, а вас, землян, вообще не понимаю. Мне даже разговаривать с вами трудно :)) Ответ принят?

Comment: Не очень. Так что насчёт добавления? Как его оформлять в таких случаях? В справочниках об этом не сказано. Вы опять не ответили.

Comment: Я не знаю. Задайте пжста вопрос на форуме.

Comment: Никто не знает, потому что этого нет в справочниках. Думаю, что лучший вариант — это поставить тире. По принципу усиления знака.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Я заработал восемь месячных зарплат за два дня, ****потому что** с каждого приведенного человека оставлял себе справедливую комиссию.***

Это обычное СПП с придаточным причины, на причинное значение указывает союз «потому что». Основным знаком является **запятая**, тире ставится **в особых случаях**, когда требуется увеличенная пауза. Эта тема рассмотрена у Розенталя: [Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142).

2. (1) *Начались проблемы* (какие именно?) – (2) ***когда снимали офис,*** (3) ***договорились заплатить потом.***

Это сложное предложение, состоит **из  двух частей**: одного простого предложения (1) и СПП из двух предложений (2) и (3). Отношения между двумя частями **пояснительные**. Для их обозначения требуется более сильный знак, чем запятая (тире или двоеточие).

3. *Где и как заработать достаточно денег, чтобы и жилье снять, и детей прокормить (**у одного из которых ДЦП**).*

Здесь дополнительная информация выделена и заключена в скобки.

Это предложение можно редактировать: *Где и как заработать достаточно денег, **чтобы снять жилье и прокормить детей, у одного из которых ДЦП.***

В этом случае получается СПП **с последовательным подчинением придаточных,** между которыми ставятся запятые.

Использование **одиночного союза И** позволяет упростить конструкцию, не ставить лишнюю запятую и включить дополнительную информацию в основное предложение.

Comment: Ой-ой-ой. 1. Спрашивается, не что поставить, а допустимо ли тире. Не ошибка ли это? Если нет, то зачем оно там? 2. *Для их обозначения требуется более сильный знак* — зачем там более сильный знак? Можно ссылку на правило? А в первом примере не пояснительные отношения? Если нет, то какие? 3. Вы самую важную информацию, самую главную проблему ставите на самый последний план, будто это ерунда. А автор решил поставить интонационное тире, чтобы подчеркнуть её.

Comment: И не надо мне предлагать дать свой ответ. Вы же не ответили. Вы просто решили сказать о том, какой знак там лучше. Но вопрос в другом: по какому правилу там стоят тире, или это ошибка (так делать вообще нельзя)?

Comment: В первом случае тире - это ошибка (нет оснований, дана ссылка на Розенталя). Во втором случае тире необходимо между ДВУМЯ частями сложного предложения  (это вы должны понимать сами). В третьем случае  я использовала скобки,  а не тире, а при редактировании оставила только запятые. Почему - объяснила. Речь там идет о способах оформления дополнительной информации.

Comment: 1. А почему нельзя интонационное тире? А почему нельзя присоединение за счёт усиления знака? 2. Уже понял вашу мысль. Но у меня иначе: *Начались проблемы в то время, как [когда] снимали офис.* Нужен контекст. 3. Скобки ни к чему. В скобках наименее важная информация, а у нас важная, её желательно подчеркнуть интонационным тире.

Comment: Добавлю контекст по второму предложению.

Деньги израсходовали за неделю. Звонили в столицу и просили прислать ещё. Но там нам не спешили отвечать. 
Начались проблемы - когда снимали офис, договорились заплатить потом, потому что мы же от Ирины Хакамады - кандидата в президенты. Из квартиры нас выгнали за неуплату, и мы стали жить в офисе.